# Machine learning self-learning book?

Tags: machine-learning, references, data-mining

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Machine learning cookbook / reference card / cheatsheet?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12386/machine-learning-cookbook-reference-card-cheatsheet)

I wonder if there is a good self-learning textbook for machine learning? I am particularly looking for those in application-level, not so much theoretical. I wouldn't mind a math-heavy book, as long as you guys think it is suitable for self-learning.

Thanks!