# Advanced statistics books recommendation

Tags: generalized-linear-model, pca, maximum-likelihood, references, saddlepoint-approximation

There are several threads on this site for book recommendations on [introductory statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/421/what-book-would-you-recommend-for-non-statistician-scientists) and [machine learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20040/machine-learning-self-learning-book) but I am looking for a text on advanced statistics including, in order of priority: *maximum likelihood, generalized linear models, principal component analysis, non-linear models*. I've tried [Statistical Models](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521734495) by A.C. Davison but frankly I had to put it down after 2 chapters. The text is encyclopedic in its coverage and mathematical treats but, as a practitioner, I like to approach subjects by understanding the intuition first, and then delve into the mathematical background.

These are some texts that I consider outstanding for their pedagogical value. I would like to find an equivalent for the more advanced subjects I mentioned.

- [Statistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393929728), D. Freedman, R. Pisani, R. Purves.
- [Forecasting: Methods and Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471532339), R. Hyndman et al.
- [Multiple Regression and Beyond](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0205326447), T. Z. Keith
- [Applying Contemporary Statistical Techniques](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0127515410), Rand R. Wilcox
- [An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R - (PDF Released Version)](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/), Gareth James, Daniela Witten, Trevor Hastie and Robert Tibshirani
- [The Elements of Statistical Learning:Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction. - (PDF Released Version)](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/), Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman (2009)

Comment: I wonder... how does the Hyndman et al. book treat the topics you list above? The normal treatment of these issues in _forecasting_ is quite specific to the field, so I would not expect one to learn a lot for application to general statistics from a forecasting book.

Comment: @StephanKolassa The books I listed are just examples of introductory statistics that I mentioned for the pedagogical value.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Maximum likelihood: [In all Likelihood](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198507658) (Pawitan). Moderately clear book and the most clear (IMO) with respect to books dealing with likelihood only. Also has R code.

GLMs: Categorical Data Analysis (Agresti, 2002) is one of the best written stat books I have read (also has R code available). This text will also help with maximum likelihood. The third edition is coming out in a few months.

Second on my list for the above two is Collett's [Modelling Binary Data](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584883243).

PCA: I find Rencher's writing clear in [Methods of multivariate analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471418897). This is a graduate level text, but it is introductory.

Comment: I agree.  I may be prejudice because I think he references my bootstrap bppk and not many people do.

Comment: Your books are great. :) If the question had asked  for a bootstrap book, they would have been on my list.

Comment: +1 for Collet's book. It contains lots of useful data sets.

Comment: Thanks to all for the excellent selection. I chose this answer simply because is short in recs and offers more breadth in terms of subjects treated (PCA, likelihood, multivariate analysis). I will only know which books are best after reading them, of course. Agresti is not included here but it has strong support by the other posters.

Answer (score 21):

**Some books on Likelihood Estimation**

- [*](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/institute-of-mathematical-statistics-lecture-notes-monograph-series/Differential-geometry-in-statistical-inference/toc/10.1214/lnms/1215467056) Amari, Barndorff-Nielsen, Kass, Lauritzen and Rao, *Differential geometry in statistical inference*.
  $-\small{\text{Geometrical approach for proving existence, uniqueness and other properties of MLE.}}$
- [*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Saddlepoint-Approximations-Applications-Statistical-Probabilistic/dp/0521872502) Butler, *Saddlepoint Approximations with Applications*.
  $-\small{\text{Saddlepoint approximations to the MLE on complicated models.}}$
- [*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521866731) Cox, *Principles of Statistical Inference*.
  $-\small{\text{A basic reference on MLE.}}$
- [*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Inference-Asymptotics-Monographs-Statistics-Probability/dp/041249440X) Cox and Barndorff-Nielsen, *Inference and Asymptotics*.
  $-\small{\text{Likelihood, pseudo-likelihood, approximation theorems and asymptotics explained by}}$
  $ \small{\text{two exponents in this area.}}$
- [*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0801844436) Edwards, *Likelihood*.
  $-\small{\text{A reference for a general discussion on this concept.}}$
- [*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Course-Sample-Chapman-Statistical-Science/dp/0412043718) Ferguson, *A Course in Large Sample Theory*.
  $-\small{\text{Contains classical results on asymptotic properties of point estimators.}}$
- [*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387904581) Kalbfleisch, *Probability and Statistical Inference II*. $\spadesuit$
  $-\small{\text{Introductory book containing interesting basic results such as the continuous }}$
  $\small{\text{approximation to the likelihood which is not always explained.}}$
- [*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Theory-Point-Estimation-Springer-Statistics/dp/0387985026) Lehmann and Casella, *Theory of Point Estimation*.
  $-\small{\text{Classical results on point estimation, an essential reference.}}$
- [*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9812386947) Pace and Salvan, *Principles of Statistical Inference: From a Neo-Fisherian Perspective*.
  $-\small{\text{A good reference on a school of thought becoming more and more popular:}}$
  $\small{\text{the Neo-Fisherian.}}$
- [*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198507658) Pawittan, *In All Likelihood: Statistical Modelling and Inference Using Likelihood*.
- [*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471024031) Serfling, *Approximation Theorems of Mathematical Statistics*.
  $-\small{\text{More rigorous book, here you can find the mystical "regularity conditions".}}$
- [*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Likelihood-Methods-Statistics-Statistical-Science/dp/0198506503/ref=pd_sim_b_1) Severini, *Likelihood Methods in Statistics*.
- [*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387953825) Shao, *Mathematical Statistics*.
  $-\small{\text{Classical results, good as a textbook.}}$
- [*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000PY3NU0) Sprott, *Statistical Inference in Science*. $\spadesuit$
  $-\small{\text{Basic reference on likelihood, profile likelihood and classical statistical modelling.}}$
- [*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Asymptotic-Statistics-Statistical-Probabilistic-Mathematics/dp/0521784506) van der Vaart, *Asymptotic Statistics*.
  $-\small{\text{A general reference on: modes of convergence, properties of MLE, delta method,}}$
  $\small{\text{ moment estimators, efficiency and tests.}}$
- [*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521839718) Young and Smith, *Essentials of Statistical Inference*.
  $-\small{\text{A more recent book on: Likelihood, pseudolikelihood, saddlepoint approximations,}}$
  $\small{p^*\text{ formula, modified profile likelihoods and more.}}$

$\spadesuit$ Suggestion for the OP

Comment: Are these listed in a particular order (e.g., your favorite to your least favorite) or not?

Comment: @Jake As my memory brought them back. I will include more as soon as I manage to recall them and then I will organise them in alphabetical order.

Comment: @Procrastinator Thanks for the exhaustive list, but I am more interested in specific recommendations focused on the criteria I described rather than a large list.

Comment: @RobertKubrick I do not quite understand your comment, but of course, it is a matter of taste. I am focused on books dealing with some aspects of likelihood estimation. I can tell you some particular aspects if you wish. This topic is too extensive to be summarised in a couple of books ... and believe me, I am not choosing books randomly.

Comment: @Procrastinator I have to pick 1 or 2 books, so I would like a specific recommendation that match my top-down approach. If you have the books I listed for introductory statistics you can tell what I'm looking for.

Comment: I am familiar with some of the books and for the ones I know I think Procrastinator has identified books that fit the criteria.  But Robert Kubrick what do you expect of us.  This is a difficult question and we serve you best by giving you a good list.  in the end you have personal choices to make and we don't know you well enough to pick for you.  We are not saying buy every book on the list .  But you can go to amazon and take a peek inside.  Read the customer reviews and the publisher descriptions.

Comment: With some you might even want to check to see which professional journals have reviewed the books and go read those reviews.  Then make a decision based on your criteria which could involve price and many subjective things.  At leat we narrow 1000 books down to say 12 or 20 and you take it from there.

Comment: @MichaelChernick ok, I'm sorry I was a bit harsh but I'm trying not to reproduce another amazon list. Why not to sort this list by some criteria, maybe pedagogical value?

Comment: @Procrastinator I noticed you added a sign for more specific recommendation. Thanks! (how did you get that spades character displayed anyway?)

Comment: @RobertKubrick I think you were quite correct that I was not answering your question precisely. I believe Kalbfleisch's book is a great start for this topic. Not too advanced, but it covers important concepts. Also, the exercises were carefully chosen and it can be used as a textbook. After that, I would go for Sprott, Cox and Pawittan (in that order). The rest are more mathematically rigorous, focusing on asymptotical properties of the estimation. The command to obtain this symbol is `$\spadesuit$`.

Comment: @RobertKubrick Your request for categorization seems reasonable.  I think Gung got us doing that for you as a gorup.

Comment: I dont think this list is what the OP asked for, the texts here is to mathematically advanced given that he asks for "intuition first".

Answer (score 13):

My guess is that, for your requirements, the best book on *generalized linear models* is probably:

- Agresti's [Introduction to Categorical Data Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471226181)

There are other books that might be considered better, but I suspect would be less appealing to a practitioner who would prefer to avoid dense mathematics:

- Agresti's [Categorical Data Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471360937) (his primary text),
  is good for practitioners, but is denser
- McCullagh & Nelder's [Generalized Linear Models](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0412317605),
  is, I hear (I've never tried it), the bible for this, but demands considerable mathematical sophistication
- Dobson's [Introduction to Generalized Linear Models](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584889500),
  is *possible* to get through, but still pretty mathematically dense, IMO

As for your other topics, I'm afraid I don't know of books for them, but maybe others can make some recommendations.

Comment: McCullagh & Nelder certainly demands some mathematical sophistication, but I think "completely impenetrable for all but very advanced mathematical statisticians" overdoes it. I think it's less mathematically demanding than, say, Hogg & Craik.

Comment: Sorry about the hyperbole, @Peter, I've edited the comment. (However, that was in line w/ what I've heard; I note that I haven't actually read it.)

Comment: Good suggestions @Gung.

Comment: Peter did you mean Hogg & Craig.  Bob Hogg has a new coauthor in the recent editins Elliot Tanis.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, thanks. We could probably use some of your expertise here; we have suggestions for MLE, GLiMs, & 1 possible suggestion for PCA, but nothing for *non-linear models*. Care to give it a shot?

Comment: Oops, yes. Hogg and Craik. Well, back when I attempted to read it, those were the authors :-).

Comment: I would recommend anything by Agresti. He's very high on the clarity/sophistication index. That is, at any given level of mathematical sophistication, Agresti writes clearly, compared to others.

Comment: +1 For Dobson and Barnett reference. This book is concise and contains good examples.

Comment: Funny, I've known statisticians who find Agresti's Introducing CDA harder to understand than because it skips over a lot of the explanations.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if these are at the level you're looking for, but some books I've found useful-

GLMs - McCullagh and Nelder is the canonical book

PCA - [A User's Guide to Principal Components](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471471348) - despite the title it does go into some degree of depth on the topic

Answer (score 8):

I really like Larry Wasserman's books "All of Statistics" and "All of Nonparametric Statistics". They are very readable, and cover a lot of ground quickly.

Comment: (+1) I had not realized these (well-received) books included advanced topics as well as introductory material.

Comment: The only problem is that the book is too brief.

Answer (score 7):

The Nonlinear Models books that I like and rely on are (1) [Bates and Watts](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470139005) and (2) [Gallant](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471802603).  Both are published by Wiley.

Comment: Oops, @Gung and I were editing at the same time to fix the links. Now neither edit is there! OK, now I think it's right

Comment: +1, thanks Michael. I'm sure that will be helpful from the OP. BTW, the way I do links is to copy the link on the other page, double-click / highlight the word or phrase that I want to serve as the hyperlink here, & then click on the button above the text window next to the quotation mark that looks like 3 links from a chain. That opens a wizard where you can paste the web address. Cheers

Comment: I'm sure the book is good but $202!

Comment: Wiley books are a little more expensive than other publishers but this is not far from the going rate for advanced statistics books.  I got mine long ago when they were much cheaper.  But the answer is then to borrow it from a technical library or get it used.  Used copies of texts like these often sell for considerably less evenin good condition, much like buying a used car.

Answer (score 4):

For Bayesian analysis (including imprecise analysis), I'm going to put in big plugs for:

- Bernardo, J.M. and Smith, A.F.M. (2000) *[Bayesian Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047149464X)*. Wiley: Chichester.
- Gelman, A. *et al* (2013) *[Bayesian Data Analysis (Third Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439840954)*. CRC Press: Boca Raton.
- Walley, P. (1990) *[Statistical Reasoning with Imprecise Probabilities](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0412286602)*. Chapman and Hall.

That last book, by the brilliant Peter Walley, is an eye-opener on different ways of doing sensitivity analysis, and the fact that this can be built into probability theory at an axiomatic level.

Answer (score 3):

Mehta (2014) [*Statistical Topics*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1499273533) (ISBN: 978-1499273533) is good intermediate level statistics story telling.  Doesn't cover much of you topics you noted above though.

Answer (score 1):

One really simple introductory statistics book is Andy Field's "Discovering Statistics using R" - also available for SPSS.
It contains a lot of nice examples and is even fun to read. Less precise, though compared to other books, but with very little mathematical formulations and lots of text. I found it easy for a basic start, and am still using it from time to time.

Comment: That's a reasonable suggestion, but I think it isn't quite what the OP is asking for.

Comment: +1. Andy Field's books are not at all what this question is about so far as I can tell.