# Frequentist Methods for Bayesians

Tags: bayesian, references, frequentist

Over time I've learned that many (most?) methods used in classical statistics can be interpreted as evaluating a Bayesian model in some plausible way while I find the standard explanations much less intuitive.

So I was wondering whether there are any resources which explain standard stats methods in a Bayesian manner?

Comment: And vice-versa would be good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Introduction to frequentist statistics for Bayesians](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/313608/introduction-to-frequentist-statistics-for-bayesians)