# What is the best book about generalized linear models for novices?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, references

I'm still pretty new to generalized linear models, and I struggle with a lot of the notation in most of the GLM texts I've picked up. Are there extremely popular GLM books that lend themselves better to readability?

Comment: You might try perusing this thread: [advanced-statistics-books-recommendation](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33197/), which includes some discussion of GLiMs. In general, I'm not sure if this question is answerable w/o more info. Do you want a mathematically dense book, eg? What is your background? Etc.

Comment: I would not want a mathematically dense book. I'm a population geneticist, and my interest is very much an applied one.

Comment: Try [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Regression-Categorical-Dependent-Quantitative-Techniques/dp/0803973748) it covers many of the models. A text that uses "general linear models" in the title is likely to be mathematical

Comment: In the linked thread, I recommended Agresti's Intro book. That has relatively little math. I suspect that might be the best book for you. What is the book you're reading now?

Comment: @gung Agresti's book is excellent. A little more advanced that Long. I see the 3rd edition of Agresti is out now.

Comment: @PeterFlom, I have skimmed some parts of Long, but haven't read all of it or in depth. Do you think it's easier than Agresti's *Intro* book? Agresti's full book is more comprehensive & I don't usually recommend it to the people I work w/, but I've always thought the Intro book was pretty clear & easy.

Comment: @gung Hehe. I haven't read Agresti's *intro* book, only the big one. I missed that word in your comment, sorry (I saw the main book recced in the linked thread).

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/209531/is-there-a-glm-bible

Answer (score 9):

For a new practitioner, I like Gelman and Hill.

[Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/)

Ostensibly the book is about Hierarchical Generalized Linear Models, a more advanced topic than GLMs; the first section, though, is a wonderful practitioners guide to GLMs.

The book is light on theory, heavy on disciplined statistical practice, overflowing with case studies and practical R code, all told in a pleasant, friendly voice.

Answer (score 7):

I am a big fan of Agresti's *[Categorical Data Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470463635)*.

I have read Agresti's Intro book but found it missing key interpretations for how generalized linear model is built and how it works. For example, you may not need to know how the binomial distribution and logit link work if you only want to fit a logistic regression. However it is annoying when you have read the chapter and started to wonder about it but couldn't find it in the book.

The McCullagh and Nelder GLM book is hard to read. It contains everything you need to know but lacks the derivation for the key results.

Luckily Agresti's *[Categorical Data Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470463635)* presents a good balance.

Comment: A more complete answer would also state the benefits of the mentioned titles.

Answer (score 4):

As a complete beginner myself, I found [Foundations of Linear and Generalized Linear Models](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118730038) by the celebrated author of *Categorical Data Analysis* Alan Agresti to be helpful. Language is fluid, though some exposure to Linear Algebra is assumed.

Answer (score 2):

I really liked [Mixed Effects Models with Extensions in R - Zuur, et. al](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387874579). It's a followup to their older book Analysing Ecological Data (2007). They do a good job of motivating the models, along with plenty of visual examples to explain what GLMs look like. They also strike a good balance between, theory, application and discussion. Plus they have all codes and datasets on their website, so you can immediately apply what you've learned.