# rigorous statistical-inference book recommendation

Tags: references, inference

I'm a first-year graduate student working on probability and I am learning statistical inference by myself, I have skimmed  through a few books like Casella /Hoggs but I find they omitted lots of details, for example, they didn't introduce the conditional expectation, so there are only proofs in discrete case about "sufficient statistics "  "factoring theorem ", etc. could you recommend me a book for graduates or doctor degree that cover basic ideas of statistical inference and rigorous proofs? thanks!

Comment: One book that I would not recommend is "Mathematical Statistics" by Shao.  In my opinion this book takes formality too far and attempts to subsume everything within measure theory, which I don't think is a particularly useful approach.  "The Theory of Point Estimation" and "Testing Statistical Hypotheses" by Lehmann seem to be quite popular.

Comment: There are several good recommendations here:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33197/advanced-statistics-books-recommendation      For you, especially Young and Smith, Essentials of Statistical Inference.

Comment: Then how about first probability (Probability and Measure by Billingsley), then statistical inference  (Trilogy by Lehman: Theory of Point Estimation, Testing Statistical Hypotheses, Elements of Large Sample Theory)?

Answer (score 3):

One book not mentioned above which I quite like is [Theoretical Statistics, Topics for a Core Course](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387938389) by Keener. It is relatively rigorous but quite readable at the same time. Personally though, I think a subset of Theory of Point Estimation by Lehmann, Mathematical Statistics by Shao, and Keener should cover almost all the topics at the level you want.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the book *Mathematical Statistics* by Keith Knight, a very friendly  introduction that covers all the basics you need to know to study statistics at a high level.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Testing Statistical Hypotheses](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387988641#aboutAuthors) by Erich Lehmann and Joseph Romano. I also like Statistical Inference by Casella and Berger.