# Market researcher looking for book recommendation

Tags: regression, bayesian, references, multivariate-analysis, survey

As a market researcher I am frequently around discussions on multivariate techniques, regressions (linear and logistic), working with survey data, choice based designs, weighting data and occasionally Bayesian analyses.

Is anyone aware of a good book or few books that will take me from surface level knowledge deeper into the weeds?

My current level of knowledge around statistics is fairly limited, I understand distributions, concepts of regressions, variance, p-values, etc. but would like to see if there are some structured options that explain things clearly/

Comment: This is a request for book recommendations, which is within our mandate. I see nothing that is too broad about this. I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: @gung: I think there's a case for trying to keep to one field of application or area of statistics per question. Market researcher interested in multivariate techniques, time series, & support vector machines;  entomologist interested  in multivariate techniques, regressions, & working with survey data - it could go on for ever.

Comment: That's a reasonable point, @Scortchi. There are certain techniques that are common in market research, but they span what statisticians might think are different topics, eg, standard stats stuff, some survey stuff, multidimensional scaling in psychometrics, market basket in ML, etc. I'm guessing that there is a stats for market research book that has intros to the set. That's what I think the OP is looking for. If there isn't such a thing, & you need 5 different sets of unrelated recommendations, this would be too broad.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this book recommended:
Bayesian statistics and marketing by Peter E Rossi
http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470863676.html
http://www.perossi.org/home/bsm-1

Answer (score 0):

You could start with Gelman and Hill's book https://www.amazon.co.uk/Analysis-Regression-Multilevel-Hierarchical-Analytical/dp/052168689X   which is very good.  It doesn't cover all you ask about, but it will bring you to a deeper level of understanding in regression, part of what you ask for.   After that one, there are many possibilities for good books,  you could have a look at  [Advanced statistics books recommendation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33197/advanced-statistics-books-recommendation/33230#33230)

Comment: Thank you! I have added the Gelman and Hill book to my list. I also just ordered Marco Taboga's Lectures on Probability Theory and Mathematical Statistics which looks like it could fill in a broad range of potential knowledge gaps. I will keep an eye out for any additional recommendations.