# A good Machine Learning Book

Tags: machine-learning, references

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Machine learning self-learning book?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20040/machine-learning-self-learning-book)

I am a researcher on Machine Learning and I generally try to refer to Andrew Moore's Tutorials and Simon Haykin's Neural Networks.

I am looking for a book which works in some detail with easy language and good exercises and recent concepts.

My problem is I have a Humanities background, and I always ask questions.

I am thinking of the book by Christopher M. Bishop / Andrew Ng's Tutorial.  Are they fine? Or do you have any other suggestion?

I generally prefer a downloadable version.

Comment: @chl I second that. I really do not understand why this question has not been closed as a duplicate or made cw. I have already double posted an answer to a similar question because the consensus was "not a duplicate" and I am fine to triple post it if it is the same for this question.