# Overview of (common) classifiers and their characteristics

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Machine learning cookbook / reference card / cheatsheet?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12386/machine-learning-cookbook-reference-card-cheatsheet)

Each classifier has it's own advantages and disadvantages.

E.g. train/test speed, classification/regression (and how many classes can be handled), how many degrees of freedom, suitable/not suitable for abstract kinds of datasets (of possible to say), how interpretable is the resulting model (like for max-ent: importance of single features), and so on and so on

Do you know a good overview? If not, would you be in to create one?

Comment: Ah, found something. Here is a question: What is the difference between your question and this one ? [Machine learning cookbook / reference card / cheatsheet?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12386/machine-learning-cookbook-reference-card-cheatsheet)