# Reference on how to choose models

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, data-mining

I wonder if there is any good and easy to understand book on reviewing on when should a particular statistical model (binomial, logistic regression, etc) be used?

My background is in statistics, but most of my work is developing MLE estimation algorithm using matrix calculus.  I am now starting to focus more on data analysis, which comes in many different ways, and I don't have a good understanding which models are most proper.

For example, I know for binary observations I should use logistic regression, but I don't know under which situations I should use a non informative prior (e.g. Jeffreys' prior).  Also, since there are so many choice of models, I don't know in a broad way which one to pick.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked this (aggregated) thread: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12386/machine-learning-cookbook-reference-card-cheatsheet I think you'll find it quite helpful.

Comment: I would consider non-parametric or semiparametric methods whenever possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this flowchart for machine learning: http://peekaboo-vision.blogspot.ru/2013/01/machine-learning-cheat-sheet-for-scikit.html