# Machine learning courses: maths explained

Tags: machine-learning, references

I'm looking for a Machine Learning course that would give the maths behind algorithms rather than simply teach how to apply them. I've looked at Udacity Into to Machine Learning and Andrew Ng's course on Coursera, and they both seem too applied to me. Any recommendations of textbooks would also be much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps this helps? http://nzhiltsov.blogspot.nl/2014/09/highly-recommended-books-for-machine-learning-researchers.html It contains a link to the web archive of measuringmeasures.com (which is http://web.archive.org/web/20101102120728/http://measuringmeasures.com/blog/2010/3/12/learning-about-machine-learning-2nd-ed.html) as well, which seems to be down nowadays.

Comment: If Andrew Ng's maths is not enough for you then you're probably not looking for the maths of machine learning but those of statistical learning, for which I would highly recommend [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Elements-Statistical-Learning-Prediction-Statistics/dp/0387848576/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1501149183&sr=8-1&keywords=the+elements+of+statistical+learning).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add on to @Digio, I would recommend Abu-Mostafa's [Learning From Data](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1600490069), which contains enough statistical learning mathematics to get you excited and wanting more.

Answer (score 5):

Note, Andrew Ng has a more mathematical course in [Stanford Online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UzxYlbK2c7E&list=PLA89DCFA6ADACE599) not Coursera.

Recommendations would always be subjective, for me, I personally like

[The Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf)

[Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf)

Both books are classical books in machine learning community and freely available.

Related question can be found here.

[Machine learning cookbook / reference card / cheatsheet?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12386/machine-learning-cookbook-reference-card-cheatsheet)

Answer (score 4):

Try to dig deeper in a specific topic. Ngs course only scratches the surface, but other more specific courses are more theoretical/mathematical.

Bayesian networks/ Markov networks:

[Probability graphical models](https://www.coursera.org/learn/probabilistic-graphical-models-2-inference/home/welcome) is a theoretical advanced coursera course on Bayesian networks/Markov networks. [The book](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/probabilistic-graphical-models) is even more theoretical. It is full of proofs.

Neural Networks:

[Neural Networks for Machine Learning](https://www.coursera.org/learn/neural-networks) is also a rather theoretical course as it is really profound. Nonetheless it is not as mathematical as the PGM course I mentioned above.

---

However if you want to understand the theory of Machine Learning itself and not the algorithms you can go for a textbook. In this case go for what @digio proposed.

Answer (score 3):

This (archived) [edX machine learning course from Columbia](https://www.edx.org/course/machine-learning-columbiax-csmm-102x-0) explains a lot of underlying math. For example they show regularized linear regression and probabilistic matrix factorization from Bayesian (Maximum A Posteriori) perspective.

[Understanding Machine Learning](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/) is a (freely available) textbook that takes computational learning theory approach, and contains derivations and calculations/estimation of VC dimension of classifiers.

Comment: is all of the math you mentioned still relevant in 2018/2019 or how has it changed? what type of math should i be learning as a base for machine learning right now? ive done some searching and the newest material regarding this that i can find dates back to 2017, and i know that ML has been growing in the meantime

Comment: @user2230470 I'd say that math for most machine learning didn't change in last 10 or 20 years. I mean math for basics, more specific models might need understanding some different things (for example there are lots of hard math in Generative Models, like Wasserstein distance in WGANs or Variational Inference in VAE)

Comment: hasnt the popularity of activation functions changed from sigmoid to relu tho? ive started learning linear algebra. multivariable calculus is another one that ive heard. it would just be nice to understand the different types of mathematics that are generally used in the field

Comment: I don't get what activation functions have to do with that. They're defined using arguably high-school math.

Comment: don't the Sigmoid and ReLU functions involve different types of mathematics?

Comment: I don't get what you mean. If you know what a maximum operation and exponential function is, they hardly involve 'different types of mathematics'. BTW people use ReLU as an activation much longer than one year.